# Compare: reCaptcha Security Preference options

Tags: recaptcha

Compare: reCaptcha Security Preference options

Can anyone please point me towards documentation where I can see the differences among "Easiest for users", "Most secure" and ".. in between .."?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: According to the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq), The main change is that "Easiest for users" provides more flexibility for users without JavaScript, which apparently shows a traditional Captcha. It is probably safe to assume that the more secure, the more harsh the policies (Such as spam, VPN, and suspicious activity)

Comment: (with a link or two, that could've been an answer!)

Answer (score 7):

"There is always a battle between usability and security," [says human-computer interaction lecturer Nan Jiang](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/captcha-automation-broken-history-fix).

So it literally does just what it says. If you want your reCAPTCHA interactions to be easiest for users, that is, you want to minimize the difficulty for users, use the "Easiest for users" option. Use "Most secure" if you want to maximize for security and stop robots at the cost of usability if necessary. Use the middle setting if you want both ease of use and a higher level of security.

In my experience with reCAPTCHA v2, the "Easiest for users" setting rarely requires the average user to solve a challenge. And "Most secure" always requires at least one captcha is solved.

According to [this guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/versions) by Google, by default only the most suspicious traffic will be prompted to solve a captcha:

> The invisible reCAPTCHA badge does not require the user to click on a
>   checkbox, instead it is invoked directly when the user clicks on an
>   existing button on your site or can be invoked via a JavaScript API
>   call. The integration requires a JavaScript callback when reCAPTCHA
>   verification is complete. **By default only the most suspicious traffic
>   will be prompted to solve a captcha. To alter this behavior edit your
>   site security preference under advanced settings.**

[About reCAPTCHA Invisible v2](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/captcha-automation-broken-history-fix):

> This system uses Google's AI to look for signs of human behaviour. It
>   runs in the background detecting movements of a mouse, how long it
>   takes to click on a page, and removes the 'I am not a robot box' from
>   webpages. The firm's security blog says the Invisible system, which
>   launched in March 2017, has "enabled millions of human users to pass
>   through with zero click everyday".

Comment: I posted links to documentation which was what you requested. Don't punish me for answering the question when so far no one else has tried.