# Google ReCaptcha v3 score is always 0.9

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I've implemented recaptcha v3 per the docs, but in our contact form when I do the callback to get the token and parse it in the backend, I'm getting a score of 0.9... all the time. Well ONE came back at 0.7, but we're getting considerable amounts of bot spam which shouldn't be at 0.9 one would think.  We went to v3 because v2 was giving just as much spam.

If you have normal scores, can you answer a couple quick questions?

- You loading it on every page (in the template), or just your contact form
- What (if anything) are you using actions for, the docs just kinda show "submit" and I'm not sure what else to issue a challenge for that isn't a "submit"...

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are running on the Google ReCaptcha non-enterprise version? As you can see from this Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/interpret-assessment#interpret_scores), not sure if you're aware of this by default there's only 4 scores i.e., 0.9, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1.

If you're getting 0.9 all the time means... Google's ReCaptcha v3 is not working! or they are trying to get you to subscribe to the Enterprise version :(

Comment: ...are you kidding me, EUGH

Answer (score 0):

To test a low score you can simulate a browser with custom user-agent, for example "Googlebot/2.1"

Screenshot from my chrome dev tools
[image: custom user-agent in chrome dev tools]

Comment: I suppose yeah, but it's that EVERYONE bot or human is 0.9 just regardless of anything... it's not that I need to test below 0.9. It's that everything is 0.9 all the time you know?

Comment: I remember there is a setting in the Captcha' backoffice where you can set the strength of the security.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829874/compare-recaptcha-security-preference-options